# help with a proof on Doob's Submartingale inequality - application of chebychev's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am stuck on a final step of the proof, we have that $(X_n)$ are non negative submartingale, and $c>0$. We let $T = \inf \{n: X_n > c \} \wedge N$ which is a stopping time. Let $E \{ \text{max}_{0\leq n\leq N} X_n \geq c \}$

In the final line of the proof, I have that $E(X_T 1_{E}) \geq cP(E)$ and this is stated as a direct consequence from Chebychev's ienquality. I don't see how this follows from Chebychev's at all, as chebychev states $cP(X_T \geq c) \leq EX_T$, but here we have $cP(  \text{max}_{0\leq n\leq N} X_n \geq c )$
can anyone explain please

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it follows from Chebyshev's inequality, but the trick is somewhat similar to the one used in the proof of Chebyshev's inequality. Note that
\begin{equation}
cP(E) = \int_\Omega c \mathbb{1}_E dP \leq \int_\Omega X_T \mathbb{1}_E \,dP = \mathbb{E}[X_T \mathbb1_E]
\end{equation}

and as $c \leq X_T$ trvially. This gives your result.